# If the iPad 2 is not HD, why does Apple advertise them as able to watch HD movies?

Tags: ipad, resolution

If the iPad 2 and iPad mini do not have native HD resolution, then why does Apple market them to be able to watch HD movies? Isn't '720p' 1280 x 720, yet the iPad 2 or mini is 1024x768?

Comment: What sort of answer do you seek?

Answer (score 5):

I imagine this is a wording thing, there is a difference between benig able to "watch HD movies" and "watch movies in HD".  The iPad can take a HD source, and scale it to display.  Commonly (although not officially) HD modes can be denoted by their number of scan lines (720p = 720 progressive, or non-interlaced, horizontal rows of pixels), and in this case the iPad 2 has 768 rows.

Comment: It can also play at 720p over AirPlay to an Apple TV and 1080p with Apple Digital AV Adapter or Apple VGA Adapter. (See: Apple's [iPad 2 Sepcifications](http://www.apple.com/ipad-2/specs/) under TV and Video.)